# Get array value from different fields with the same CLASS in jQuery and use AJAX to send the data to PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get array value from different fields with the same CLASS in JavaScript and use AJAX to send the data to PHP

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control subject" placeholder="Subject name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control subject" placeholder="Subject name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control subject" placeholder="Subject name">
```

here are the inputs with the same CLASS `subject`

so in my java script i'll want to get all these values and push them into an array called `subjectArr`
example result for `subjectArr` is `var subjectArr = ['English', 'Maths', 'Physic'];`
so now i'll send `subjectArr` through AJAX to the back-end;

Comment: That is invalid html. The `id` attribute must be unique. You should switch it to `class` if you want multiple elements.

Comment: You can grab them with an attribute selector like `document.querySelectorAll('.form-control[id="subject"]')`, but I completely agree with the first comment.  Instead of circumventing the invalid html, you should fix your html

Comment: you are right, that is absolutely correct; but overall i hope you understand the question?

Comment: We do.  You're asking how to work with duplicate ids, and ignoring that that is invalid.  https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id  *"An element can have an associated unique identifier (ID)"*

Comment: i changed the ID to CLASS; Now lets assume we have a class

Comment: so what you want to do with these inputs??

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.subject')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('subject')` will find all the elements with that class.  And then you can process them as you need.

Comment: the concept is to grab all the values from those inputs and store them in an array; as i mentioned.

Comment: If using jQuery is an option, that should be included as a tag.  For jQuery it would just be `$('.subject').map(it => it.value).get()`

Comment: so i was thing king var tasks= new Array();
$('input[name^="task"]').each(function() 
{
tasks.push($(this).val());
});

Comment: If you find yourself creating an array, and then writing a jquery statement that loops over things, and pushes things to the previous array, you are essentially rewriting the `map()` method that already exists.

Comment: @Edward Bee Kamara you have multiple input fields eith same name??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `map()` and `get()` to return array of values.

```js
var myArray = $('input[type="text"]').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(myArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="PHP">
<input type="text" value="JAVASCRIPT">
```

Comment: What's the point of the class if you don't use it?